# Not able to identify an element using webdriver though IDE identifies it easily

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having tough time to find out an input box and enter values in it through webdriver
This is the HTML code for the input box

```
<div class="OCYEKPD-qb-a input-field-error" id="gwt-debug-lineItem-mainSizeWidget" style="display: block;">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel OCYEKPD-qb-c goog-inline-block" style="display: none;"></span>

    <div style="display: inline;">
        <input class="OCYEKPD-qb-e OCYEKPD-qb-l" style="width: 15px;" type="text">

        <div class="OCYEKPD-ld-a" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code i am using to identify and send the values

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-lineItem-mainSizeWidget")).sendKeys("300x250");
```

But webdriver skips the box instead of entering values and moves to the next line,No error or exception thrown.

Comment: here is the HTML code  <div class="OCYEKPD-qb-a input-field-error" id="gwt-debug-lineItem-mainSizeWidget" style="display: block;"><span class="gwt-InlineLabel OCYEKPD-qb-c goog-inline-block" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span><div style="display: inline;"><input type="text" class="OCYEKPD-qb-e OCYEKPD-qb-l" style="width: 15px;"> <div class="OCYEKPD-ld-a" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div> </div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-lineItem-mainSizeWidget"));
divElement.findElement(By.tagName("input")).sendKeys("300x250");
```

The code first identifies the div container where the input element resides. Then from this container it searches for the first input element it can find within this container and sends your string.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked, i was trying to do this since last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find element by class since the input tag doesn't have an id. You should be able to do:

`WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(By.ClassName("OCYEKPD-qb-e"));`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID("gwt-debug-lineItem-mainSizeWidget")).sendKeys("300x250");
```

You are missing the underscore and ID needs to be capitalized.

Comment: ID can never be in capital. Don't confuse OP